# Mule 4 Is it possible to share dataweave code modules as jar file and use them in my projects by adding the jar as a dependency

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I would like to bundle my commonly used DataWeave functions in a mule-plugin jar file and then add the plugin as dependency to my mule applications (so that I could reuse my DW code in all my applications).

The goal is to share the code as a versioned dependency.
Basically, what I want to do is very similar to how shared flows work, except I want to do the same for DataWeave modules and functions.

I can create the mule-plugin and add it as a dependency but I don't see how can I reference the DW functions from the plugin in my main application.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is easier than I thought it would be.
Here is an example:

https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/data-weave-sample-module

As it turns out I can import the DW modules from plugin in the same way as if they are part of the main project.

Comment: This is not a mule plugin dependency but rather a standard Java Jar file. Mule finds the module because it is a file in the classpath (ie a resource in the source project).